# Does the Quran have the following verse about the tree from which Adam was forbidden?

Tags: quran, verses

The Quran has Genesis so logically I was thinking it would have the following verse.
If not what is the closest verse?

> And the Lord God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.
> — Genesis 2:16–17

Answer (score 2):

> وقلنا يا آدم اسكن أنت وزوجك الجنة وكلا منها رغدا حيث شئتما ولا تقربا هذه الشجرة فتكونا من الظالمين
>
> And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat therefrom in [ease and] abundance from wherever you will. But do not approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:35](http://legacy.quran.com/2/35)</sup>

> ويا آدم اسكن أنت وزوجك الجنة فكلا من حيث شئتما ولا تقربا هذه الشجرة فتكونا من الظالمين
>
> And "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat from wherever you will but do not approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:19](http://legacy.quran.com/7/19)</sup>